JSON to change SharePoint Form "Save" button to "Submit"
I have the following JSON below applied to my SharePoint new add item:
There are currently two default buttons "Save" and "Cancel"
How can I add to the code below to rename the "Save" button to say "Submit"
"elmType": "div",
"attributes": {
    "class": "ms-borderColor-neutralTertiary"
},
"style": {
    "width": "99%",
    "border-top-width": "0px",
    "border-bottom-width": "1px",
    "border-left-width": "0px",
    "border-right-width": "0px",
    "border-style": "solid",
    "margin-bottom": "16px"
},
"children": [
    {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
            "display": "flex",
            "box-sizing": "border-box",
            "align-items": "center"
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                    "iconName": "AddNotes",
                    "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-themePrimary",
                    "title": "Details"
                },
                "style": {
                    "flex": "none",
                    "padding": "0px",
                    "padding-left": "0px",
                    "height": "36px"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
            "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-24"
        },
        "style": {
            "box-sizing": "border-box",
            "width": "100%",
            "text-align": "left",
            "padding": "21px 12px",
            "overflow": "hidden"
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "elmType": "div",
                "txtContent": "Supplier Request For Information"
            }
        ]
    }
]

}
tried various online suggestion but cant get this to work by just changing the JSON

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
